# How to get the total duration of a project

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I was given a list of dictionaries with different keys and values, one of them is the duration of an activity and each activity has predecessors, I need to calculate the total duration of the project and for that, I need to find out when the activities start and finish and then get the maximum value of the finish values. I do not know how to write code to get the start and finish values.

```
activities = [
 {'Cost': 10000, 'Duration': 5, 'Name': 'Activity 1', 'Predecessors': None},
 {'Cost': 8000, 'Duration': 3, 'Name': 'Activity 2', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 1']},
 {'Cost': 2000, 'Duration': 15, 'Name': 'Activity 3', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 2', 'Activity 1']},
 {'Cost': 7000, 'Duration': 16, 'Name': 'Activity 4', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 2']},
 {'Cost': 5000, 'Duration': 20, 'Name': 'Activity 5', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 4']},
```

That is a portion of what I was given.

```
def get_total_project_duration(activities: list) -> int:
    start = 0
    finish = {}
    for activity in activities:
        predecessors = activity['Predecessors']
        if not predecessors:
            finish[activity['Name']] = 0 + activity['Duration']
        else:
            for pred in predecessors:
                for value in activities:
                    if value['Name'] == pred:
                       start += value['Duration']
            finish[activity['Name']] = start+activity['Duration']
            start = 0
    totalDuration = max(finish.values()) 

    return totalDuration
```

This is what I tried but it didn't work out.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "didn't work out"?

Comment: It returned the number 98 but I'm not sure if that is just the sum of all the finish values or some other value. I was not given the correct number we should get, but it marked it as incorrect when I turned it in.

Comment: Depending on the definition of the exercise, you may need to recurse through the predecessors: 3 has 2 and 1 as predecessors, and 2 has an additional 1 as a predecessor. If you're meant to count each predecessor once, you need to recurse; if not, you need to keep track of which predecessors you've already counted for any given task.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). To be able to help, we need to know the correct result and exactly how to get it so we can check your code. See [mre]. For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of problem where you have to be shown the "trick" first.

The key here is that you can only know an activity's end point if all of its predecessors have already finished.  Thus, you need to keep going through the list, and for every entry that isn't finished, find out of all of its predecessors are done yet.  If it has, you can remember it's end point, and move on to the next one.

Note that it's possible to construct a graph with a loop or with an unconnected "island" that would cause this code to loop infinitely.  I presume they won't feed you one of those.

```
activities = [
 {'Cost': 10000, 'Duration': 5, 'Name': 'Activity 1', 'Predecessors': None},
 {'Cost': 8000, 'Duration': 3, 'Name': 'Activity 2', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 1']},
 {'Cost': 2000, 'Duration': 15, 'Name': 'Activity 3', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 2', 'Activity 1']},
 {'Cost': 7000, 'Duration': 16, 'Name': 'Activity 4', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 2']},
 {'Cost': 5000, 'Duration': 20, 'Name': 'Activity 5', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 4']}
 ]

def get_total_project_duration(activities: list) -> int:
    start = 0
    finish = {}
    unfinished = len(activities)
    while unfinished:
        for activity in activities:
            if activity['Name'] not in finish:
                latest = 0
                for pred in activity['Predecessors'] or []:
                    if pred not in finish:
                        latest = -1
                        break
                    latest = max(latest, finish[pred])
                if latest >= 0:
                    print(latest, activity)
                    finish[activity['Name']] = latest + activity['Duration']
                    unfinished -= 1

    return max(finish.values())

print(get_total_project_duration(activities))
```

Output:

```
0 {'Cost': 10000, 'Duration': 5, 'Name': 'Activity 1', 'Predecessors': None}
5 {'Cost': 8000, 'Duration': 3, 'Name': 'Activity 2', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 1']}
8 {'Cost': 2000, 'Duration': 15, 'Name': 'Activity 3', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 2', 'Activity 1']}
8 {'Cost': 7000, 'Duration': 16, 'Name': 'Activity 4', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 2']}
24 {'Cost': 5000, 'Duration': 20, 'Name': 'Activity 5', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 4']}
44
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reshaping activies to make lookup easier...

```py
## Reshape activities to make searching by name easier
activities = [
    {'Cost': 10000, 'Duration': 5, 'Name': 'Activity 1', 'Predecessors': None},
    {'Cost': 8000, 'Duration': 3, 'Name': 'Activity 2', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 1']},
    {'Cost': 2000, 'Duration': 15, 'Name': 'Activity 3', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 2', 'Activity 1']},
    {'Cost': 7000, 'Duration': 16, 'Name': 'Activity 4', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 2']},
    {'Cost': 5000, 'Duration': 20, 'Name': 'Activity 5', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 4']},
]
activities = {activity["Name"]: activity for activity in activities}
```

Now I would approach this problem by recursively finding the list of distinct activities that must be processed for any given activity.

Note, I have assumed that any given activity once completed is enough to satisfy every required prerequisite for that task, and that no two tasks run in parallel.

```py
def distinct_names(name):
    names = set([name])
    for name in activities[name]["Predecessors"] or []:
        names = names.union(distinct_names(name))
    return names
```

Now to find a given activity's duration we just need to take the list of distinct activity and add up their durations...

```py
for activity in activities.values():
    total = sum(activities[name]["Duration"] for name in distinct_names(activity["Name"]))
    print(activity["Name"], total)
```

Giving one:

```
Activity 1 5
Activity 2 8
Activity 3 23
Activity 4 24
Activity 5 44
```

The overall duration for that set of activities would be the maximum:

```
print(max(
    sum(activities[name]["Duration"] for name in distinct_names(activity["Name"]))
    for activity in activities.values()
))
```